# Order of initialization in Scala

Tags: scala

Having a Scala class with a companion object

```
object BB {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
}

class BB {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

I was wondering if the object was working just like in Java where If I remember the first thing to be evaluated in the class was the statics and then finally the constructor.

But here when I create a new instance of BB and check the times, the object it´s not evaluated first.

```
object main extends App {
    val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    private val bb = new BB

    println(s"App:$time ")
    println("Instance" + bb.time )
    println(s"Static ${BB.time }")
}
```

So then I've been wondering how the initialization in Scala works?

Regards.

Comment: The companion object is initialized on the first access to it.

Comment: so just to be 100% sure, only when I invoke BB.time it´s when all that contains the object BB it´s initialized? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you mean everything that is contained in `BB`, then yes, that will be initialized when `BB.time` is invoked (unless the field is defined as `lazy val` or `def`).

Comment: sure!, so then we can asume object is lazy by design. Thanks a lot for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in a comment, companion objects are initialized on the first access to it. More broadly, all `object`s in Scala are initialized lazily. Quoting [the Scala Language Specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) (for version 2.12):

> Note that the value defined by an object definition is instantiated lazily. The new *m$cls* constructor is evaluated not at the point of the object definition, but is instead evaluated the first time *m* is dereferenced during execution of the program (which might be never at all).

You can confirm it with a little experiment (where I'm going to use an `Iterator` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis` so that this can be easily hosted and ran on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/d3Hu3bRKS2K31b2okhFE4Q/1)):

```
val ticks = Iterator.from(0)

object BB {
  val time = ticks.next()
  val foo = "bar"
}

class BB {
  val time = ticks.next()
}

new BB().time
new BB().time
BB.foo
new BB().time
BB.time
```

The last five expressions will cause `BB` (the object) to be initialized when its `foo` member is accessed, making the very last expression evaluate to 2.

As mentioned before, you can play around with this code [on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/d3Hu3bRKS2K31b2okhFE4Q/1).